# Why multiplying by base b works when converting fractions from one base to another?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, binary, decimal-expansion

Suppose we have a decimal like 0.25 and we want to convert it to binary, one of the methods goes like this:

Multiplying the decimal by 2 repeatedly:

```
0.25 * 2 = {0}.50 | {0}
0.50 * 2 = {1}.00 | {1} 
0.00 
--------------------------
                   .01
                   0.01
```

Why does this work?

Comment: Multiplying a number by 2 is effectively shifting it over one bit to the right, so that is why your method works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $r$ be a real number between $0$ and $1$.  The first digit in the base $b$ representation of $r$ is the number of times $1/b$ goes into $r$ -- or, to be more precise, it's the largest whole number $n_1$ with the property that $$n_1\cdot\frac{1}{b} \le r$$
This condition is equivalent to
$$n_1 \le br$$
Another way of saying this is that the first digit is the largest whole number less than or equal to $br$.  So to find the first digit of the base $b$ representation, multiply $r$ by $b$ and take the integer part.

Similarly, the second digit of the base $b$ representation of $r$ is the largest whole number $n_2$ with the property that
$$n_2 \cdot \frac{1}{b^2} \le r - \frac{n_1}{b}$$
Equivalently,
$$n_2 \le b^2 r - b\cdot n_1$$
Therefore you can find the second digit by computing $b^2 r - b\cdot n_1$ and just keeping the integer part.  This continues for each digit in the base $b$ expansion.

Answer (score 1):

If the number is more than $\frac 12$ you will get a $1.xxx$ when you multiply by $2$.  You put that $1$ on your decimal to indicate the value of $\frac 12$.  Then you take what's left and do it again. If what is left was is greater than $\frac 12$ then that part was originally greater than $\frac 14$.  You get a $1$ at this point and so that one indicates $\frac 14$ and so one.

If the numbers were less than $\frac 12$ you get a $0$.

Answer (score 0):

When converting integers, you divide repeatidly by $b$ until you have nothing left to be divided. When converting fractions, you multiply repeatidly by $b$ until you are left with zeros (or your digits start cycling). Same insight, but in opposite direction.